# MSI bit of CR register in RC is not changing

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I am using nucleo stm32L476 series controller. I am writing the drivers from scratch. I observed my controller is running on MSI clock at 4 MHz(0x6 in MSIRANGE) in RCC CR register.
I want to modify the clock frequency for which i need to make MSI bit off (MSI = 0). When i am trying to do so, the bit is not changing

can anybody suggest why so?. is it due to the fact that no clock will be running if I make MSI bit 0 ?

I tried the below code
RCC->CR &= ~(1 << 0);
RCC->CR |= (0x8 << 4);
but observed that the value itself in MSI bit is not changing.

Comment: hold up, are you trying to disable the clock the CPU is running from?

Comment: if you want to change the clock then x = RCC->CR; x&=(~(0xF<<4)); x|=8<<4; RCC->CR=x;    what you are doing, looks bad you need to read the manual.

Comment: you certainly do not need to turn msion off, please read the manual first.

Comment: so you are saying that first i should clear all the bits of MSIRANGE and set to desired value. But in manual it is clearly said that :Note: Warning: MSIRANGE can be modified when MSI is OFF (MSION=0) or when MSI is 
ready (MSIRDY=1). MSIRANGE must NOT be modified when MSI is ON and NOT 
ready (MSION=1 and MSIRDY=0). So how is that possible what you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

As Ilya said in the comments, you cannot switch off MSI if it serves as system clock, directly or indirectly (i.e. as source to PLL which is selected as system clock).

However, you don't need to switch MSI off to change its frequency. Quoting from RCC_CR.MSIRANGE bitfield description in RM0351:

> Warning: MSIRANGE can be modified when MSI is OFF (MSION=0) or **when
> MSI is ready (MSIRDY=1)**. MSIRANGE must NOT be modified when MSI is ON
> and NOT ready (MSION=1 and MSIRDY=0)

(emphasis mine)

JW

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood that i can not switch off MSI as it is system clock for me. And the manual says i cannot change the frequency if MSI bit is ON. Then how can I modify MSIRANGE bits ? should i use MSIRDY bit?

Comment: After reset, you will have MSION==1 and MSIDRY==1. According to the highlighted line above, that's an a state which in which it is OK to change MSIRANGE. So, without any further ado, just simply change MSIRANGE and that's all.